# Chromatic polynomial of $K_4-e$

Tags: coloring

I need to find chromatic polynomial of graph $K_4-e$ where $K_4$ is complete graph with $4$ vertices.
So here we have a "square" and one diagonal in it. And now, starting from upper left, and going clockwise we have vertices 1,2,3,4(where we have edge 13 and no edge 24). So, I first thought to color vertex 1 on t ways, then vertex 3 on $t-1$ ways, and then for 2 and 4 we have $(t-2)^2$ ways. But if we first color 1 and then 2 and 4, and on the end 3, we have $t(t-1)^2(t-2)$. So I'm not sure which of these two is correct, and how to know which vertex to color first, second, etc.

Comment: The chromatic polynomial of $K_4$ and $K_3$ are easy to compute. The first vertex can be colored with $x$ colors, the second with $(x-1)$, the third with $x-2$,... So for $K_4$ it is $x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ and for $K_3$ it is $x(x-1)(x-2)$. You could then apply [deletion-contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial#Deletion%E2%80%93contraction). Deleting $e$ from $K_4$ gives you your graph, while contracting it gives you $K_3$.

Comment: And if we have $2$ isolated vertices with $K_4-e$ then we have two cases, to color those two with same or different color? And for $K_4-e$ everything is same?